# how to display totally different webpage when accessed by mobile or tablet?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, responsive-design, responsive

what i mean is that if user open website from large screen such as computers or smart tv than it would have different set of controls which are in relation to that screen resolution And when users surfs that from mobile the same page will have different controls relational to the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

using media queries in css you can display different controls in different screens.

Disadv:

- you need to render all controls in both times

  ```
  @media (max-width:768px) {
      .listbox {
          display: none;
      }

      .dropdown {
          display: block;
      }
  }

  @media (min-width:768px) {
      .listbox {
          display: block;
      }

      .dropdown {
          display: none;
      }
  }

      <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="ListBox1" CssClass="listbox">
          <asp:ListItem Text="Chennai"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Mumbai"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Hyderabad"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Bangalore"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Delhi"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:ListBox>

  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="dropdown">
          <asp:ListItem Text="Chennai"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Mumbai"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Hyderabad"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Bangalore"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Delhi"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
  ```

Comment: can you please elaborate that how to use media queries to add or remove controls, panels, content, etc to make device responsive.

Comment: I have problem with Listbox in mobile screen, so i hide listbox in mobile screen and dropdown in desktop